# Yii2 log to DB in one row instead two

Tags: yii2

I turned on logging to DB.
On every error, Yii creates two rows in DB table: one row with an error message, and second with `application` category with global variables.

I turn on logging to DB in config `web.php` like this:

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
            'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Then I create table in DB with Yii default migration:
`yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/log/migrations/`

Can I merge both rows in one?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend yii\log\DbTarget class and override export() function in it to fit your needs.